# Can noncomputable real be represented as a continued fraction?

Tags: real-analysis, computability

Can a non-computable real be represented as a continued fraction?

The reason I'm asking is that I thought the continued fractions were a construction of the reals, but a continued fraction also looks a lot like an algorithm to me.

Comment: Every real number has a representation as a simple continued fraction , the catch is that the (infinite) continued fraction is uncomptable if the number is.

Comment: @peter thanks, it sounds like the answer is "yes," but I can't think of an example or an argument.

Comment: *a continued fraction also looks a lot like an algorithm to me* --- Not if the continued fraction "coefficients" do not follow a pattern that can be the output of an algorithm. Pretty much the same issue with the digits in the decimal expansion of a real number, and I'm sure you'd agree that some real numbers have decimal expansions that cannot be the output of an algorithm.

Comment: If we could determine (in principle) ALL entries of the simple continued fraction of the given number, we could use this to compute the number (again in principle). This however cannot be the case , since the given number is uncomputable. So , there cannot be an algorithm to find the continued fraction.

Comment: However, a patternless continued fraction seems possible not only for uncomputable numbers (where it is forced to be patternless) , but also for numbers like $\pi$ or $2^{1/3}$. $e$ is an example for a continued fraction with a pattern.

Comment: @Peter, it looks like pi might be representable using a non-simple continued fraction (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html). I'm not sure if this is true, or if it means that the answer to my question might be different for simple vs. non-simple continued fractions.

Comment: @MaxHeiber Yes, but not a simple continued fraction. If we allow any kind of describable continued fraction, we will of course have much less numbers with pattern-less continued fractions. Of course, an uncomputable number can not have any describable continued fraction.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro and @ Peter happy to accept as an answer if you copy/paste your comments to the answer box. Thanks for your help